# Asymptotics of the multipartition function

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Recall that the multipartition function $p_k(n)$ counts the number of $k$-tuples of partitions $\lambda^1,\ldots,\lambda^k$ of numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ with $a_1+\cdots+a_k=n$.  It has a generating function:
$$\sum_np_k(n)x^n=\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-x^n)^{-k}$$
Asymptotics of $p_k(n)$ are known for $k$ fixed and $n\to\infty$, see Theorem 4 in [Murty](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/partition.pdf).

> Is there a known asymptotic formula for $p_k(n)$ which is uniform in both variables as $k,n\to\infty$?

If this is not known, I would also be interested in partial results (upper/lower bounds).

Comment: Are you aware of the Nekrasov-Okounkov hook-length formula? (1.3) on p3 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.1398v1.pdf